# Laravel - custom caching property (getter?)

Tags: php, laravel, caching

I just can't understand how to do in "the laravel way" what the example below describes without messing with model properties from the database.

To be clear, I'm looking for some core Laravel magic so I don't need to do the `$memoryCache` thing manually

Imagine the `getProp()` method is a database call that I don't want to run more than once, ie keeping the result in memory until PHP is done running.

Example class:

```php
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Test extends Model
{
    public $memoryCache = [];

    public function propA() {
        return $this->getProp() . '_A';
    }

    public function propB() {
        return $this->getProp() . '_B';
    }

    private function getProp() {
        if (!array_key_exists('prop', $this->memoryCache)) {
            echo "Do this only once\n";
            $this->memoryCache['prop'] = 'DBData_' . rand(1,5);
        }
        return $this->memoryCache['prop'];
    }
}
```

Running it:

```php
$test = new \App\Models\Test;
echo "{$test->propA()}\n";
echo "{$test->propB()}\n";
```

Output:

```
Do this only once
DBData_5_A
DBData_5_B
```

**Bonus!**

Would be even better if I could somehow use PHP getters/setters so that I could just call them like class "properties" like this:

```php
$test = new \App\Models\Test;
echo "{$test->propA}\n";
echo "{$test->propB}\n";
```

Comment: you can access them as properties, they are called accessors, https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor

Comment: May be you should have a look at https://github.com/spatie/once

Comment: @lagbox I know about accessors, but A) they are transforming an db attribute and B) they don't cache the result which is the main point here

Comment: you don't need them to do all of that, you are already doing the caching in `getProp` ... you just have to change the method name of those 2 methods and they would be accessors

Comment: @Donkarnash Thanks, but isn't that just a fancy way of doing what the example is doing? I was more wondering if there is a core Laravel way of doing this

Comment: @lagbox Sorry for not being very clear. I was wondering if Laravel has this caching mechanism so I don't have to do the whole `$memoryCache` thing

Comment: @Fractalf nope, you will have to write code to do it, you could use the actual cache system but that would be pointless for something that is only the the lifetime of that object

Comment: even eloquent itself has to do this same type of check for relationships when using the dynamic property ... if it isn't loaded it tries to load it and caches the result, same type of check happening

Answer (score 1):

There really isn't anything built in anywhere that you could use, what you are doing is fine; this is the same type of check that Eloquent does when you use the dynamic property for a relationship. It checks if it has been loaded and if not loads it then returns the loaded relationship (that is saved on the instance, cached in the same type of way).

The "Bonus" part:

If you want to access those as properties instead of methods you can do that with an "accessor":

```
public function getPropAAttribute()
{
    return $this->getProp() . '_A';
}
```

Now you can access the `propA` property of the model:

```
$model->propA;
```

[Laravel 8.X Docs - Eloquent - Accessors and Mutators - Defining an Accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor)

Comment: No this is not cached. Look at the comments in the question

Comment: you don't need to cache the calls to the accessor ... the call to `getProp` is what is cached, if this isn't the case your example doesn't make any sense since in each of those methods you are calling `getProp` which is the same thing happening here .... `getProp` is doing the caching

Comment: Thank you for answering part of my question :)